Masstransit Constraints Exception
I am using MassTransit Outbox feature. I often get exception like this
EntityFramework.Exceptions.Common.ReferenceConstraintException: Reference constraint violation ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23503: update or delete on table "InboxState" violates foreign key constraint "FK_OutboxMessage_InboxState_InboxMessageId_InboxConsumerId" on table "OutboxMessage".
When this is happening I have to explicitly remove messages from tables.
How to avoid getting this error ?
Here Is config code snippet.
busConfig.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<AppDbContext>(outboxConfig =>
{
    outboxConfig.UsePostgres();
    outboxConfig.UseBusOutbox();

    outboxConfig.QueryMessageLimit = 50;
    outboxConfig.DuplicateDetectionWindow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
});


Without a complete repository, troubleshooting is not possible. I'd suggest going through support.

To avoid the exception, do one of the following: modify the code so that referencing rows are deleted prior to deleting referenced rows; use deferred constraints so that referential integrity is checked when committing; or change foreign key constraints to include ON DELETE CASCADE or ON DELETE SET NULL (and possibly ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL). Without the actual application code, there's not much more the SO community can do to help.

After some research I found out that, the QueryTrackingBehavior of Entity Framework was QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking which caused problems. After turning the tracking behavior into QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll, all problems gone.
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>((sp, opt) =>
{
    opt.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll);
//...
});

